# Ipod Classic 80GB will not synch in Rythmbox or Banshee etc in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ipod

I have tried getting my Ipod Classic 80GB to synch in Rythmbox or Banshee, running on Ubuntu 13.04. Rythmbox crashed, Banshee starts but then seems to get stuck. This is a new installation and has had all current updates. Is there anything I can do, or do I just have to ait for the fix? I tried googling the problem, but just found out that it seems to affect Clementine as well. Many thanks for reading and bigger thanks to the person who can fix this.
Ian (complete noob)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it's this beauty :(

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1132215